# Laravel: How to save text file in UTF-8 without BOM

Tags: php, laravel, utf-8, character-encoding

**Problem:** We need to save txt file in UTF8 without BOM. However, string with special chars like **C'est français** are getting saved directly into UTF8 without BOM. However, string without special chars like **This is French** is getting saved in ASCII.

**Objective:** We want everything to be saved in UTF8 without BOM. Below is the code of laraveel save function:

**Code:**
`Storage::disk('local')->put($filePath, $string)`

Comment: Hi @MartinAmu, it's not working.

Comment: Is Iconv extension installed on your server? If not please install or ask your server admin to install it. http://php.net/manual/en/iconv.installation.php

Comment: Yes @MartinAmu, it's already installed. It's running on iconv library version 1.14

Comment: And what output from dd($stringUTF); ?

Comment: It's null only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245888/discussion-between-bugcoder-and-martin-amu).

Comment: in php to write utf8 you should make sure you save .php file in utf8 format .. make sure your editor isn't save ascii but utf-8  take example with notepad++ https://youtu.be/QbbmhYAhYYg?t=12  after you change the format save the file test and upload it on server then try to access it .. starting with this then will allow you to do more specific job of what you try to archieve